# Como eu posso executar um arquivo .rdl (Reporting Service) com Report Viewer sem usar o servidor?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, reporting-services

Boa Tarde,
Estou precisando de uma solução para rodar os arquivos .rdl local sem usar o servidor do Report Services, preciso usar o arquivo local.
O objetivo é usar os relatórios já existentes, com SQL Server e Report Services, em outro banco de dados. Alguém tem alguma sugestão?
Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Meu banco de dados é MySQL, então meus relatórios são RDLC. Ambos usam o mesmo xml, mas o RDLC permite não ter a conexão e nem a query. Desta forma eu faço a query e conexão com o banco via C# e envio para o RDLC como um DataSource que emite se encarrega de gerar e emitir o relatório.

É possível converter o RDL pra RDLC: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252109(v=vs.80).aspx

Isto feito, crie uma função básica para emitir seus relatórios diretamente no ResponseStream, tipo esta:

```
private void Renderizar(string nomeReport, Formato formato, Dictionary<string, object> dataSources, Dictionary<string, object> parameters = null)
    {
        var deviceInfo = string.Format("<DeviceInfo>" + "  <OutputFormat>{0}</OutputFormat>" + "</DeviceInfo>", "PDF"|"Excel");

        var report = new LocalReport();
        using (IO.StreamReader arquivo = new IO.StreamReader(Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Relatorios/{0}.rdlc", nomeReport)))) {
            var strre = arquivo.ReadToEnd();
            report.Refresh();
            report.LoadReportDefinition(new IO.StringReader(strre));
        }

        foreach (var item in dataSources) {
            var DataSource = new ReportDataSource(item.Key, item.Value);
            report.DataSources.Add(DataSource);
        }

        List<ReportParameter> @params = new List<ReportParameter>();
        if (parameters != null) {
            @params = new List<ReportParameter>();
            foreach (var item in parameters) {
                @params.Add(new ReportParameter(item.Key, item.Value.ToString()));
            }
        }

        string mimeType = "";
        string ext = "";
        string encoding = "";

        Warning[] warnings = null;
        string[] streams = null;

        if (@params != null) {
            report.SetParameters(@params);
        }

        var bytes = report.Render(formato.ToString(), deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out ext, out streams, out warnings);

        Response.ContentType = mimeType;
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);


    }
```

Aí para chamar eu uso:

```
var dataSources = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dataSources.Add("DataSourceNameDENTRO_DO_REPORT", List<Objetos>);

var parametros = new Dictionary<string, object>();
parametros.Add("Data", "VALOR PARA EXIBIR COMO UM PARAMETRO NO REPORT");

Renderizar("NomeRelatorio", "PDF", dataSources, parametros);
```

Comment: Ótima solução, agora só uma dúvida, como você chamaria um rdlc que possui subreport com parâmetro? Obrigado.